# Facebook API logging in from app without pop-up authorization

Tags: facebook, flash, api, air

I'm developing a flash based photo booth application. The application runs on a system with only a touchscreen monitor - no keyboard or mouse.

I currently have it set up so that users can email their customized picture when they're finished, but I was hoping to allow users to post their image to Facebook as well.

I've downloaded the AIR desktop Facebook API and have successfully connected to Facebook, but what I can't figure out is how to get rid of the login/authentication pop-up while logging in to an account.

Is there any way to script the user login directly?

The problem I have with the pop-up is that it's in a completely different window than my application and not controlled by the "soft" onscreen keyboard I have in my application (because it's running on a touchscreen with no keyboard or mouse).

Does anyone know of any way to post to Facebook from a Flash/AIR application without the pop-up authorization window?

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much looking and trying I'm 99% sure (I'm still holding on to a little hope!) that what I want to do is not possible.

You can not allow users to log in to there Facebook account and post pictures to their wall from a Flash .exe or desktop AIR app using the Facebook desktop API on a kiosk-type system that uses only a touchscreen with no keyboard or mouse. The log in will open in a new window and you will not be able to send input to it - obviously any onscreen keyboard you may have in your app will not input to the new window.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook explicitly does NOT want there to be a way for you to log in without the popup window: this limits attempts to programmatically log in as a user (and do things as the user).

One possible solution may be to use a full redirect (as covered [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/#no-jssdk) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)) and specify the `display` parameter as **page** or **touch**.

Comment: Absolutely, I understand WHY Facebook wants to maintain control over the login. I was hoping that perhaps Facebook and Adobe had considered the use of AIR in a standalone touchscreen kiosk. I'll check out these links, thanks Femi!

Comment: As near as I can tell, redirecting and setting display as touch would involve decompiling, editing and then recompiling the API (.swc with libraries)... I'm not sure that even after doing that the touch display would help me link the login window to my onscreen keyboard... Thanks for the suggestion though Femi, I really appreciate it.